# ActiveModel Validate form has a negative value if true else validate form has a positive value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm trying to validate a form field in a Rails app one of two ways, depending on the params passed in. If my object has the param `allow_negative: true`, I want:

```
validates :amount, numericality: {less_than_or_equal_to: 0}
```

otherwise I want:

```
validates :amount, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0}
```

When I try to just do this:

```
validates :amount, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0}, unless: :allow_negative
validates :amount, numericality: {less_than_or_equal_to: 0}, if: :allow_negative
```

It just executes the second instance of `validates :amount`

For reference, here is my entire class:

```
class ViewModel
    include ActiveModel::Model

    validates :description, presence: true
    validates :amount, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0}, unless: :allow_negative
    validates :amount, numericality: {less_than_or_equal_to: 0}, if: :allow_negative

    attr_reader :amount
    attr_reader :description
    attr_reader :allow_negative
    attr_reader :order

    def initialize(user, params)
      @amount = params[:amount]
      @description = params[:description]
      @allow_negative = params[:allow_negative]
      @order = Order.find(params[:order_id])
    end

  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the above works if passed an actual boolean. I was passing a string of true or false. Once I converted the value of `allow_negative` to a true bool, it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

What your code is doing is forcing either positive or negative values based on the state of `:allow_negative`. It would be more accurate to call it `:force_negative` using the structure you have there.

If you want your `:allow_negative` value to allow both positive and negative values, you'll want something like this:

```
validates :amount, numericality: true
validates :amount, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0}, unless: :allow_negative
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to make a custom validation such as the following:

```
class ViewModel
  include ActiveModel::Model

  validates :amount, numericality: true
  validate :force_negative

  private

  def force_negative
    if allow_negative && amount > 0
      errors.add(:amount, "must be less than or equal to 0")
    elsif amount < 0
      errors.add(:amount, "must be greater than or equal to 0")
    end
  end
end
```